# Redirect "Add To Cart" Button to different custom page In Magento / Add new Button in Product Page in Magento

Tags: php, jquery, magento, redirect, image-editing

I am working on **Magento website**, I want to add my image editor after product page before it add to cart and checkout page. 
I want to rename "**Add To Cart**" Button to "Image Editor" and then it redirects to my editor page and after editing image it will redirect to cart checkout page.

I have tried to doing changes in

> app/design/frontend/neoshop/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

but its not working.

Anyone done this before ??

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL like

- Simple product

> http://magentostoreurl.com/checkout/cart/add/product/productId

- Config product

> http://magentostoreurl.com/checkout/cart/add/product/productId?super_attribute[attributeId]=optionId

Comment: How can I redirect this pages and rename Add to Cart Button or rename this button ?